# Pyserial install for different python versions

Tags: python, pyserial

I initially installed python in miniconda (python3.6). So when I did `pip install pyserial` , it installed pyserial under `miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

Later I also installed python2.7. How can I install pyserial (or atleast tell it to use the above pyserial version) for python2.7?

Comment: Use `pip2` for python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

if you are using conda/miniconda you can get pyserial 3.4 now via the conda-forge channel

To install this package with conda run:
`conda install -c conda-forge pyserial`